# What is the best way to optimize this if statement?

Tags: php, performance, if-statement

I have an if statement inside a while loop thats running on each row in a database

```
if(str_starts_with($title, $search.' ') || str_starts_with($title, $search.', ') || str_starts_with($title, $extra_search.' ')){
            $points += 25000;
            $points .= $html_c * 5;
}
```

I have a lot of these if statments for different columns and the search is becoming slow is there any way to optimize it? The only thing I could think of was having an array of these $search variables then looping through them and seeing if one of them matches the title but it might become even slower.

Comment: Hard to say what is the "best" without any context, it looks a little like you're trying to roll your own search engine with ranking results. If your looking for an optimised way to run searches, I'd recommend a specific search component like sphinx, elastic, or others.

Comment: @aland yes, I am trying to make a search engine, I just did some research on your recommendations and will try to integrate them thank you.